# hbase concurrecy issue with three different thread take same row same time

Tags: php, hadoop, concurrency, hbase, thrift

I have one table in `hbase` which having 10000 thousands records. I have used `php` `thrift` library from interact with `hbase`. My question is  that I have three thread which execute on same time and take same records from table and update all three but I don't know how to prevent  it if one thread did process then other two don't want to do anything on it. Could you suggest me how can i overcome on it.

Right now what happen with me like all three process are executing but I don't want to do that one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: split the keys you are processing in 3 batches and give each one to different thread

Comment: @AdamSkywalker Could explain me in detail not understand. please help me.

Comment: your code operates on some keys in hbase, add a rule that will split all keys in 3 groups and process them separately